# IBM DB2 and Symfony - generate Entities from an Existing Database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, db2

i am trying to develop an application with the symfony framework. The entities are stored in an existing DB2 database.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

I tried the steps from the documentation. But i get an error which says:"No Metadata Classes to process". This happens if i tell doctrine to convert the existing table to an xml format.

Any ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you include your parameters.yml ?

Comment: `parameters:
    database_driver: ibm_db2
    database_host: 192.168.1.4
    database_port: '50000'
    database_name: VIADEET
    database_user: xxx
    database_password: xxxxxxxx
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: f8d57cffa2b324ce834d522ef15b164a
    database_path: null`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert --from-database yml ./src/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "YourBundle" yml
```